# Using just one post category in a wordpress PHP template

Tags: php, wordpress

Having a little issue with some PHP code, my skills in PHP aren't the strongest and I'm a little stuck at the moment.

I am working on a site which uses posts for a news page. 
We are building a blg page, and I want to use posts as well, to make it simpler for the user, however I cant seem to get the page to use just one category, its pulling every single post no matter what the category.

Here is my code for the page template.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <br /><?php echo pageWidgets($post->ID,'main',400); ?>
        </div>


<?php /*?>        <div class="contentTop2 newspad">

            <?php
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1,'category_name'=> "blog", 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
            $postslist = get_posts( $args );

            foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <?php $exclude_first_post =  $post->ID; ?>
                <div class="postNews">

                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { /* loads the post's featured thumbnail, requires Wordpress 3.0+ 
                        echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">'; the_post_thumbnail(); echo '</div>';
                    } ?>

                    <div class="newsRightPost">

                       <div class="newsTitleTop"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                       <div class="newsDateTop">Posted&nbsp;<?php the_date(); ?></div>
                       <div class="newsExcerptTop"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                       <div class="readMoreText"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">Read More >></a></div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="clearBoth">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <div class="clearBoth">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>

<?php */?>
```

I thought 'category_name'=> "blog" would sort it out for me, however it doesn't seem to work at all.

I get the blog category, but I also get every other category.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Did you try with that blog category ID? In your arguments array put instead of `category_name`, `'cat' => #ID` where `"ID` is the number of the category (you can find it by hovering on the category in Category page and looking at the link down left).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't seem to make a difference.